# Apache Cassandra metrics not showing up in prometheus

Tags: cassandra, jmx, prometheus, exporter

I Have JMX exported and prometheus configured. And trying to get the graphs we have in dse version of opscenter. How can we get them in prometheus.

Below are the metric's I'm looking for:

```
Read Requests/sec
Write Requests/sec
Write Pending/sec 
Read Pending/sec
Dropped Mutation
Co-ordinator Latency
Stream-in Data
Datacenter Message Latency
```

Comment: Few months back, I came across to similar issues, in which i want to extract hinted metrics, but it's not available in practice (even though it's mentioned in docs). So you might need to double check here first http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html. If mentioned but not available, you can raise one JIRA to cassandra team. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Grafana and add prometheus as a data source. Once done, you should be able to use PromQL for graphing the widgets in a dashboard.

You need to use the metric names depending on how you have mapped in the Prometheus config yaml.

My config has following mapping for node level metrics:

- pattern: `org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(ClientRequest), scope=(Read|Write|RangeSlice), name=(Latency|TotalLatency)><>(Count|OneMinuteRate|FiveMinuteRate)`
- name: `cassandra_$1_$2_$3_$4`

So for read requests (& write requests) per sec, I am using the metric - `cassandra_ClientRequest_Read_Latency_OneMinuteRate` - for plotting the oneminuterate.